# Python: IF Statement inside For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I want to create a new column then use another parameter as a condition to populate that column.

Here is my code how ever it doest continue to elif. Only the first argument is applying even though it did not meet the parameter I set.

```
for i in df_csrdata_2mos_Filtered_Done["Agent"]:
    if i == "unez" or i == "rmbua" or i == "destrada" or i == "amateo" or i == "cmabelison":
        df_csrdata_2mos_Filtered_Done["AgentTag"] = "Agent 1"
    elif i == "rverga" or i == "dpcaban" or i == "dgsugui":
        df_csrdata_2mos_Filtered_Done["AgentTag"] = "Agent 2"
    elif i == "gmic" or i == "jdera":
        df_csrdata_2mos_Filtered_Done["AgentTag"] = "Agent 3"
    elif i == "gras" or i == "mcsrra":
        df_csrdata_2mos_Filtered_Done["AgentTag"] = "Agent 4"
    elif i == "jcawan" or i == "rmcola" or i == "mjgamo":
        df_csrdata_2mos_Filtered_Done["AgentTag"] = "Agent 5"
    elif i == "ychaco" or i == "phondra":
        df_csrdata_2mos_Filtered_Done["AgentTag"] = "Agent 6"
    elif i == "mmorang" or i == "vsin":
        df_csrdata_2mos_Filtered_Done["AgentTag"] = "Agent 7"
    elif i == "pbong":
        df_csrdata_2mos_Filtered_Done["AgentTag"] = "Agent 8"
    else:
        print("AgentTag Done!")
```

Comment: When you say that the code "doest(sic) continue to elif" what do you mean by that? What is `df_csrdata_2mos_Filtered_Done`? What is the value of `df_csrdata_2mos_Filtered_Done["Agent"]`?

Answer (score 1):

Your if/elif is working fine.

Based on `df_` I'll assume you're working with Pandas dataframes, and in that case it's just that `df_csrdata_2mos_Filtered_Done["AgentTag"] = "X"` replaces the whole series with a new value.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})
>>> df
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
>>> df["b"] = "Agent Perry"
>>> df
   a            b
0  1  Agent Perry
1  2  Agent Perry
2  3  Agent Perry
>>>
```

If the last `Agent` would be `"pbong"`, all of the AgentTags in the df would be Agent 8.

It looks like all in all you're looking for `Series.map()` with a dict:

```
>>> agent_map = {
...     "unez": "Agent 1",
...     "rverga": "Agent 2",
... }
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"agent": ["unez", "rverga", "hello"]})
>>> df
    agent
0    unez
1  rverga
2   hello
>>> df["AgentTag"] = df["agent"].map(agent_map)
>>> df
    agent AgentTag
0    unez  Agent 1
1  rverga  Agent 2
2   hello      NaN
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use loops, here not necessary.

Better is mapping by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = {
    "Agent 1": ["unez", "rmbua", "destrada", "amateo", "cmabelison"],
    "Agent 2": ["rverga", "dpcaban", "dgsugui"],
    "Agent 3": ["gmic", "jdera"],
    "Agent 4": ["gras", "mcsrra"],
    "Agent 5": ["jcawan", "rmcola", "mjgamo"],
    "Agent 6": ["ychaco", "phondra"],
    "Agent 7": ["mmorang", "vsin"],
    "Agent 8": ["pbong"],
}

# flatten lists
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}

df_csrdata_2mos_Filtered_Done["AgentTag"] = df_csrdata_2mos_Filtered_Done["Agent"].map(d1)
```

Comment: that's sad… but whatever, don't get affected by it ;)